# How do I access the value of an array at index [i] -where the value is a property?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a for loop,

```
NSLog (@"%@", [[<array> objectAtIndex:i]-><specific_var>];
```

Each index position should have two vars and I'd like to access one of them. Thanks much.

Edited: in this case I'm trying to access a property

Comment: Provide more context. Show how the variables/properties are declared. Show your loop. Show what you've actually tried so far.

Comment: yes, and I can also see the whole array having the right information in the debugger (all the entries).

Comment: @rmaddy, context is irrelevant in this case. Under this very circumstance ... a for loop with this very NSLog statement, how do I access that property. Furthermore, the fact that there were 3 valid, totally working answers clearly demonstrates that the information was enough. Nonetheless, I'll try to give more details in the future.

Comment: The question was really "how do I access a property". The receiver being in an array or, or the array being accessed in a loop had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More easily using the literal syntax:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [someArray[i] someGetter]);
```

or is it is an array of arrays:

```
NSLog(@"%@", someArray[i][someIndex]);
```

Comment: Even if it were an array of arrays, the first two examples would still work fine... it may just not be printing what he wants it to print...

Comment: @nhgrif I'm a fan of the literal syntax. :-)

Comment: dot syntax on id? this wont compile

Comment: No, I don't mind it.  What I mean is that even if the object at index `i` of `someArray` is an array, `someArray[i]` will still print something just fine.

Comment: the second example worked @Zaph, thank you. Upvoted and I'm going to accept this answer as soon as they allow me to. :)

Comment: @Oliver Good catch! Fixed. But the SO comment now refers to the first example.

Answer (score 3):

The only time we apply `->` to an Objective-C object (other than `self`) is when we want to access the object's instance variables from outside of a method on that object.  And we almost never want to do that.

Anyway, the return type of the `objectAtIndex:` method is `id`.  An `id` has no public instance variables.

If you know the objects in your array are of a specific type, and you want to access the instance variables of those objects directly (which is generally **strongly frowned upon**), you must cast the return value to the correct type first.  Example:

```
NSLog(@"%@", ((MyObject *)[myArray objectAtIndex:i])->_myInstanceVariable);
```

But generally you are much better off using accessor methods, which usually don't require you to cast from `id` to a more specific type.

Answer (score 3):

You're far better off creating a temporary local variable. It will help you get access to the property without using `->` and make your code clearer.

E.g.

```
TheObject *object = array[i]; //same as [array objectAtIndex:i]
NSLog(@"%@", object.property);
```